# At what distance do farmers stop working the fields?

Tags: knights-and-merchants

I have made 2 farms quite far from one another. Yet the farmer from one farm continues going to the other, wasting time on traveling. (I also read this is really inefficient.) How many blocks from the house does the other farm field have to be so the farmers don't farm each others fields? Is the distance counted from the doors, or from any side of the building?

Should I count squares from the doors (red) or from building border (blue)? Here is a picture to demonstrate what I mean:

[image: farm]

Is the distance the same for all professions? Will a quarry worker not mine mountains that are further than the same distance, for example?

I'm kinda OCD about things like this, and the game is quite challenging so I need all the help I can get.

Comment: You can measure that quite simply by building a lone Farm and surrounding it by fields circle, then looking at which fields the corn was sown - those are within range.